# Select count or sum of whole table regardless of join conditions

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:
POLLS:

| POLL_ID | CONTENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 |
| 2 | C2 |
| 3 | C3 |

VOTES:

| POLL_ID | USER_ID | VOTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | U1 | 1 |
| 1 | U2 | 2 |
| 2 | U1 | 3 |
| 2 | U2 | 2 |
| 3 | U2 | 3 |

I want to query by `USER_ID`  (ex U1) and get result like this:

| POLL_ID | CONTENT | VOTE | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | C2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

But I get this:

| POLL_ID | CONTENT | VOTE | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | C2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

`V1`, `V2` and `V3` are total count of selected vote (1 to 3) for each `POLL_ID`, regardless of `USER_ID`. I want my user to know what he/she voted and what EVERYONE voted **for each poll**.
My query is like this but it skips the `POLL_ID` column filter and returns the sum of whole table.

```
SELECT
    POLLS.POLL_ID,
    POLLS.CONTENT,
    FILTERED_VOTES.VOTE,
    SUM(WHOLE_VOTES.VOTE = 1) AS V1,
    SUM(WHOLE_VOTES.VOTE = 2) AS V2,
    SUM(WHOLE_VOTES.VOTE = 3) AS V3
FROM
    POLLS
JOIN
    VOTES AS FILTERED_VOTES
ON
    POLLS.POLL_ID = FILTERED_VOTES.POLL_ID AND
    FILTERED_VOTES.USER_ID = 1
JOIN
    VOTES AS WHOLE_VOTES
ON
    POLLS.POLL_ID = WHOLE_VOTES.POLL_ID;
```

Could you please point me where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,we can join table `polls` and table `votes`,and filter the derived table to include the poll_ids which have user `c1` in them. The filtering can be easily done using a subquery in the search condition :

```
select *
from polls p
join votes v
using(poll_id)
where poll_id in (select poll_id from votes where user_id='u1')
;
-- result set
+---------+---------+---------+------+
| POLL_ID | CONTENT | USER_ID | VOTE |
+---------+---------+---------+------+
|       1 | C1      | U1      |    1 |
|       1 | C1      | U2      |    2 |
|       2 | C2      | U1      |    3 |
|       2 | C2      | U2      |    2 |
+---------+---------+---------+------+
```

Then group by the result table from the previous step using `poll_id` and `content`, and perform aggregated functions to get the desired report.

```
select p.poll_id,p.content, 
sum(case user_id when 'u1' then vote  end) as vote,
sum(case v.vote when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as v1,
sum(case v.vote when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as v2,
sum(case v.vote when 3 then 1 else 0 end) as v3
from polls p
join votes v
using(poll_id)
where poll_id in (select poll_id from votes where user_id='u1')
group by p.poll_id,p.content
;

-- result
+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+
| poll_id | content | vote | v1   | v2   | v3   |
+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+
|       1 | C1      |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |
|       2 | C2      |    3 |    0 |    1 |    1 |
+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to join both tables once and `GROUP BY` the polls table columns, it is a simple pivot:

```
SELECT
  p.POLL_ID, p.CONTENT
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.VOTE = 1 THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd) vote_1
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.VOTE = 2 THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd) vote_2
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.VOTE = 3 THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd) vote_3
FROM polls p JOIN votes v ON p.POLL_ID = v.POLL_ID
GROUP BY p.POLL_ID, p.CONTENT
```

| POLL_ID | CONTENT | vote_1 | vote_2 | vote_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | C2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | C3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R3E0H6Os)

and if you only want to know what user U! voted

```
SELECT
  p.POLL_ID, p.CONTENT
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.VOTE = 1 THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd) vote_1
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.VOTE = 2 THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd) vote_2
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.VOTE = 3 THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd) vote_3
FROM polls p JOIN votes v ON p.POLL_ID = v.POLL_ID
WHERE v.USER_ID = 'U1'
  GROUP BY p.POLL_ID, p.CONTENT
```

| POLL_ID | CONTENT | vote_1 | vote_2 | vote_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | C2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k7DVts3J)

Adding the totalvotes for each poll

```
SELECT
  p.POLL_ID, p.CONTENT
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes v1 WHERE p.POLL_ID = v1.POLL_ID) as Total_votes
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.VOTE = 1 THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd) vote_1
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.VOTE = 2 THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd) vote_2
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.VOTE = 3 THEN 1 ELSe 0 ENd) vote_3
FROM polls p JOIN votes v ON p.POLL_ID = v.POLL_ID
WHERE v.USER_ID = 'U1'
  GROUP BY p.POLL_ID, p.CONTENT
```

| POLL_ID | CONTENT | Total_votes | vote_1 | vote_2 | vote_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | C2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nXl7SgFc)

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I want to get selected user's vote for each poll and EVERYONE ELSE's votes count for that poll.

Comment: no adding meanigful column names helps, but i added he column